# Object functions and generics

Tags: java, function, object, generics

As a homework assignment, I need to restructure code that is in my textbook. The goal is to, using a findMax method and a function object technique, find the "findMax" of a Character and String array where the findMax will return the Char that is last in the alphabet and for the string, it will return the String that starts with the last letter in the alphabet ignoring case sensitivity. My question is if I have done it correctly (I obviously have some doubts)? I don't want errors or warnings. I also don't really want to copy and paste answers. I just want to get a better understanding of how I can do this. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Lab1q6 {
public static <AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
AnyType findMax( AnyType [ ] arr, Comparator<? super AnyType> cmp ){
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for(int i=1; i < arr.length; i++)
        if( cmp.compare( arr[ i ], arr[ maxIndex ] ) > 0 )
             maxIndex = i;
    return arr[ maxIndex ];

}
public static class CaseInsensitiveCompare<AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> implements Comparator<AnyType>
{
    public int compare( String lhs, String rhs )
    { return lhs.compareTo( rhs ); }

    @Override
    public int compare(AnyType o1, AnyType o2) {
        return o1.compareTo( o2 );

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] array = {"owl", "zebra", "GATOR", "Ant", "Reindeer"};
        Character [] arr = {'C', 'Z', 'A', 'R', 'S'};

        System.out.println( findMax(arr, new CaseInsensitiveCompare()));
        System.out.println( findMax(array, new CaseInsensitiveCompare()));

}

}
```

Comment: Generic types are usually defined as a single letter (T, for example). AnyType looks like a real class name. Please respect the conventions. Also, what's the use of the first compare() method in CaseInsensitiveCompare, and why is this class named that way, since it doesn't do a case-insensitive comparison at all? That comparator is not what you want. You need two separate comparator classes: one which compares Character instances in a case-insensitive way, and one which compares String instances by their first character in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you about the conventions, however, the assignment asks me to copy and paste from the book and then manipulate it. That's the only reason I am using "AnyType" even though I'd probably prefer <T>. I've changed the code so that the class now only has one compare and the parameters are AnyType lhs, AnyType rhs using a compareTo method. It technically works, but I have 2 Type Safety warnings and 1 raw type warning.